# What's this JML thing in my house?

Tags: electrical, guide

I have seen these things in various walls around my house and I am just wondering what the heck they are???

[image]

reverse image search showed no useful results so now I here asking for the help of stack exchange! Any ideas?

Comment: Does it twist off or is it permanently attached? Total guess based on "1242TVAC" but is it a port for a whole house vacuum?

Comment: Have you tried sending an email to info@johnmilsltd.co.uk?

Comment: Can you take a wider photo, so we can see the surrounding area. Are these near the bottom, top, or middle of the wall? Does it open? What's inside?

Comment: @Tester101 there is nothing around it, it is in a shoe cupboard on the ceiling bit and there are three in a row. I've had them in another property in the bathroom as well which was around the middle of the wall height wise. I am afraid they do not twist off, at least, not with my physical strength without tools.

Comment: @user20127 it does not twist off I am afraid, no.

Comment: Does a screw driver fit in the gaps around the edge of the inner ring, to pry it off?

Comment: Looks like it's held by spring clips on the top and right. "Do not dispose of in household waste" and the volt/amp ratings suggest a battery. Power for smoke alarms or exit lighting or something of that sort? Websearch company name and 1242TVAC (apparent part number) might find it.

Comment: You should try calling that number or emailing that email.